# Determine the url (or controller and action names) of a request which is unauthorized with Shiro Grails plugin

Tags: grails, shiro

I would like to be able to log the requests that my app receives that are unauthorized. Because the Shiro plugin uses an HTTP redirect to send the user to `auth/unauthorized` the request object is a fresh one and I can't get the original URL; controller/action name; or request parameters from it.

**Is there a way to determine either the original url, or the controller and action names (and request params if possible) inside the AuthController unauthorized action?**

I am looking at http://plugins.grails.org/grails-shiro/tags/RELEASE_1_1_3/ShiroGrailsPlugin.groovy as a reference of the plugin source.

Details:
Grails 1.3.7
Shiro Grails plugin 1.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem... my solution is not perfect:

a browser sends the so called referer in one of the headers which you can get through

```
request?.getHeader('Referer')
```

But the referer is nothing you really can rely on -- but most of the browsers send it.

Another solution could be the filter: try to write the current url to another variable before you call `accessControl()` in `ShiroSecurityFilters.groovy`. You can get the current URL through `request.forwardURI`.

**Update:** just verified my last assumption - this seems the cleanest solution to me:

In `ShiroSecurityFilters.groovy`, replace

```
            // Access control by convention.
            accessControl()
```

with

```
            // Access control by convention.
            if (!accessControl()) {
                session.deniedUrl = request.forwardURI
                return false
            }
```

which enables you to access the url as `session.deniedUrl` in your auth/unauthorized controller.

Comment: Sorry about slow reply. Thanks Ralf, your updated solution seems clean and simple. I think I will go with that.